# How to map a function in pandas which compares each record in a column to previous and next records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series of water levels for which I need to calculate monthly and annual statistics in relation to several arbitrary flood stages. Specifically, I need to determine the duration per month that the water exceeded flood stage, as well as the number of times these excursions occurred. Additionally, because of the noise associated with the dataloggers, I need to exclude floods that lasted less than 1 hour as well as floods with less than 1 hour between events.

Mock up data:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2014,9,5,12,00)
daterange = pd.date_range(start, periods = 10000, freq = '30min', name = "Datetime")
data = np.random.random_sample((len(daterange), 3)) * 10
columns = ["Pond_A", "Pond_B", "Pond_C"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index = daterange, columns = columns)
flood_stages = [('Stage_1', 4.0), ('Stage_2', 6.0)]
```

My desired output is:

```
                          Pond_A_Stage_1_duration Pond_A_Stage_1_events  \
2014-09-30 12:00:00                    35.5                  2   
2014-10-31 12:00:00                    40.5                  31   
2014-11-30 12:00:00                    100                   16   
2014-12-31 12:00:00                    36                    12
```

etc. for the duration and events at each flood stage, at each reservoir.

I've tried grouping by month, iterating through the ponds and then iterating through each row like:

```
grouper = pd.TimeGrouper(freq = "1MS")
month_groups = df.groupby(grouper)
for name, group in month_groups:
    flood_stage_a = group.sum()[1]
    flood_stage_b = group.sum()[2]
    inundation_a = False
    inundation_30_a = False
    inundation_hour_a = False
    change_inundation_a = 0
    for level in group.values:
        if level[1]:
            inundation_a = True
        else:
            inundation_a = False
        if inundation_hour_a == False and inundation_a == True and inundation_30_a == True:
            change_inundation_a += 1
        inundation_hour_a = inundation_30_a
        inundation_30_a = inundation_a
```

But this is a caveman solution and the heuristics are getting messy since I don't want to count a new event if a flood started in one month and continued into the next. This also doesn't combine events with less than one hour between their start and end. Is there a better way to compare a record to it previous and next?

My other thought is to create new columns with the series shifted t+1, t+2, t-1, t-2, so I can evaluate each row once, but this still seems inefficient. Is there a smarter way to do this by mapping a function?

Comment: It would help if you share the data table that you are working and what your desired output would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a quick, partial answer since no one has answered yet, and maybe someone else can do something better later on if this does not suffice for you.

You can do the time spent above flood stage pretty easily.  I divided by 48 so the units are in days.

```
df[ df > 4 ].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper( freq = "1MS" )).count() / 48

               Pond_A     Pond_B     Pond_C
Datetime                                   
2014-09-01  15.375000  15.437500  14.895833
2014-10-01  18.895833  18.187500  18.645833
2014-11-01  17.937500  17.979167  18.666667
2014-12-01  18.104167  18.354167  18.958333
2015-01-01  18.791667  18.645833  18.708333
2015-02-01  16.583333  17.208333  16.895833
2015-03-01  18.458333  18.458333  18.458333
2015-04-01   0.458333   0.520833   0.500000
```

Counting distinct events is a little harder, but something like this will get you most of the way.  (Note that this produces an unrealistically high number of flooding events, but that's just because of how the sample data is set up and not reflective of a typical pond, though I'm not an expert on pond flooding!)

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c+'_events'] = ((df[c] > 4) & (df[c].shift() <= 4))

df.iloc[:,-3:].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper( freq = "1MS" )).sum()

            Pond_A_events  Pond_B_events  Pond_C_events
Datetime                                               
2014-09-01            306            291            298
2014-10-01            381            343            373
2014-11-01            350            346            357
2014-12-01            359            352            361
2015-01-01            355            335            352
2015-02-01            292            337            316
2015-03-01            344            360            386
2015-04-01              9             10              9
```

A couple things to note.  First, an event can span months and this method will group it with the month where the event began.  Second, I'm ignoring the duration of the event here, but you can adjust that however you want.  For example, if you want to say the event doesn't start unless there are 2 consecutive periods below flood level followed by 2 consecutive periods above flood level, just change the relevant line above to:

```
df[c+'_events'] = ((df[c]           > 4) & (df[c].shift(1) <= 4) &
                   (df[c].shift(-1) > 4) & (df[c].shift(2) <= 4))
```

That produces a pretty dramatic reduction in the count of distinct events:

```
            Pond_A_events  Pond_B_events  Pond_C_events
Datetime                                               
2014-09-01             70             71             72
2014-10-01             91             85             81
2014-11-01             87             75             91
2014-12-01             88             87             77
2015-01-01             91             95             94
2015-02-01             79             90             83
2015-03-01             83             78             85
2015-04-01              0              2              2
```

Comment: YES! Thank you, I knew pandas had an intelligent way to do this but I was really twisting in the wind trying to work it out.